# Add a playable Java Swing program to GitHub Pages

Tags: java, swing, github, jar, github-pages

I recently decided to try out [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/). I have a simple Java Swing based Minesweeper project, and decided try out Pages using that repository. Since this repo is a game, I want to somehow embed the program on the web page to allow users to play the game directly in the browser, without needing to download any files.

When doing research, I came across the following ideas, yet none seem to be a correct solutions:

#### Java Applet

It seems like most popular suggestion was to create an [applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html).

```
<APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500"></APPLET>
```

From reading up on what applets can be used for, it seems like this is exactly the kind of thing I am looking for. Modern web browser like Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, however, do not support the applet plugin anymore, so using an applet does not seem to be an option.

#### Java Web Start

As an alternative to applets, some answers suggested using a [JWS application](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).

I have not yet found any good documentation explaining how to create a JWS application from my Java Swing program, and then embed it on a web page. From the little that I did understand though, it seems that the way JWS applications work is that a user clicks on a .jnlp link, the Java Web Start applications downloads all needed files, and the JWS app then launches the Java application.

The whole idea is that I want to allow users to play my game directly in the web browser, so unless I'm misunderstanding how JWS applications works, this does not seem to do what I want.

#### .jar File

The last idea was to create an executable `.jar` file. I have already created a `.jar` file to include in my repository release, but I haven't found a way to embed this file in a web page and get it to run.

The above 3 ideas are just what I came up with while looking for an answer. I have never used an applet or JWS application before, and have never added a `.jar` to a web page before, so it is possible that I misunderstood something regarding how these features work. If one of these methods are still usable, what are the steps I need to take to implement it to get my game running?

Is there any other way to add my Java Swing game to my GitHub Pages HTML page?

Comment: Why the resistance to having the app. free floating on the screen? Embedded Java apps. were always problematic from both a development and usability viewpoint. But while getting a JWS launch working can be some effort, it is a breeze for the user, and very much more workable.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would think that users would be more wary of trying out a game if it needs to be downloaded. I also think it is a nicer experience if you can right away begin playing the game without needing to click a button, or switch focus to a popup window.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Although I still would like a way to directly embed the program, since it seems like JWS is the only possible answer for now, do you an suggestions to links on how to create a JWS, or can you add some steps to your answer, because I have not yet been able to figure out how to create one?

Comment: *"..would be more wary of trying out a game if it needs to be downloaded."* Since a while ago, all Java code that was either applets or JWS launched not only needed to be digitally signed, but signed using a code signing certificate issued by a Certification Authority. That caused a security warning to pop up for the user to authorise before launch. So any which you you go, you're stuffed unless the user trusts you.

Answer (score 3):

1. *"using an applet does not seem to be an option."* Correct. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).
2. JWS the only way to embed a JWS app. was if it was used to launch an applet, and we already killed that idea in point (1).
3. Executable Jar (using a `main(String[])` method to launch it). Cannot be embedded in a web page, JWS will allow launching an executable Jar free floating on the desktop.

> ..can you add some steps (re JWS launch) to your answer..

I went to some effort putting the steps into the [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) tag. Point the mouse cursor at the tag and follow the 'info' link. But don't be fooled into thinking it's something that can be summed up in a few steps, unless they are ..very *broad* steps. So broadly:

1. Digitally sign the code.
2. Create a JNLP file that provides the JVM with the details needed to launch the app.
3. Upload the JNLP and signed Jar to the server.
4. Create a link to the JNLP.

Comment: Is this answer basically saying that my idea is not possible?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of looking at the tag. I guess I'll see if any of the "See Also" links explain the steps well. I have looked at a lot of those links already though, while doing my initial research, and most of them were not that clear, so I'm hoping one of the news links have a good explanation on how to create a JWS app. I still would love if there was a way to add the app directly to my page, but I guess this will need to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to run java code embedded in a browser is an Applet. However, browser support for applets is eroding away (as you already noted).

Java web start doesn't run your application in the browser, it is just a way to deploy an application via a web site. Then java web start takes care checking for updates and auto-updating if any are available. It is actually a pretty good way to make apps available. There are a couple of drawback though. First, to make it so the user doesn't get tons of security warnings you need a code-signing certificate from a CA and they are expensive ~$1,200 for a 3-year certificate. You can self-sign but the user gets a lot of warnings that basically tell them not to run the code. Secondly, this depends on your users having a java runtime already installed. Here is some really good documentation from Oracle for web start:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html

What I would recommend to you is to use the libgdx gaming framework (https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com). With this framework you write your game in Java then it can create an iOS version, android version, a desktop version, and what you are interested in an HTML5 version. It creates the HTML5 version using Google Web Toolkit which compiles Java to JavaScript. (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-the-web)

libgdx has pretty good documentation, has lots of tutorials available on youtube, has a pretty active stack overflow tag, and has a sub-reddit.

Since minesweeper is a turned-based game it is a tad different than a game that requires constant active rendering, but there are plenty of turn-based related links if you search google for "libgdx turn based". You will obviously need to change your game to fit in the framework.

Comment: Your list of JWS drawbacks is really informative. The more I learn about JWS, the more it seems not worth it. The main purpose of my project site is to show off my code. I just thought it would be cool to have a live playable demo, but at this rate, I can just have a link to download a normal .jar file. You are not the first to recommend libGDX to me, so maybe it really is worth learning how to use. And Minesweeper is just a simple repo I'm using to test with. I have other games as well that are a lot more complex, and if I get something working, I would apply it to the other games as well.

Comment: *"Java web start doesn't run your application in the browser, "* JWS could launch applets embedded, until browser makers killed applets. *"code-signing certificate from a CA and they are expensive ~$1,200 for a 3-year certificate"* There was one CA offering them for free, don't know if the offer is still open. *"You can self-sign but the user gets a lot of warnings"* Nope. A self-signed certificate no longer works at all.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It doesn't look like there are free ones available anymore, but there are definitely cheaper ones out there. I did a quick search and found that sites like [Certum](http://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,offer_code_signing.xml) and [StartCom](https://www.startcomca.com/) have offers for way less. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155241/cheapest-java-code-signing-certificate-not-self-signed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I had no idea you could launch applets with a JNLP (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/embeddingJNLPFileInWebPage.html). Looks like the self-signed restriction started with Java 1.7 Update 51 (https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml) although users can still run it, but have to add the domain to an exception list, which most users won't have any idea about, so in practice self-signed is indeed dead. I will tell our InfoSec guy to shop around since our code signing cert expires next month. Thanks for the info.